# Cannot find reference 'ext' in '__init__.py'

Tags: python, telebot

[image: вот скрин ошибки]Установил библиотеку python-telegram-bot, но почему-то импорт из telegram.ext подчёркивает как ошибку. Пишет Cannot find reference 'ext' in '**init**.py'
Соответственно, не даёт импортировать Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters. Что делать?

Пробовал установить пакет ext, просит обновить менеджер PIP, но он обновлён уже.

```py
import telegram
from гега import tg_bot_token
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
```

Comment: Давайте угадаю - у вас `PyCharm`? Почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248017/cannot-find-reference-xxx-in-init-py А вообще хорошо бы скриншот ошибки приложить к вопросу.

Comment: Приложил, спасибо

Comment: А вот кому-то ещё помогло такое обновление: `pip install --upgrade ipython` https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1139

Comment: И ещё добавьте в вопрос точную строку - как именно вы ставили эту библиотеку телеграма. А то бывает ставят одну библиотеку, а импорты копируют от другой библиотеки.

Comment: Понял, сейчас исправлю вопрос

Comment: А, так у меня на скрине ниже терминал открыт, там написан путь